# Connect two imported repos

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

We recently moved from GHE to BitBucket. Our DevOps team imported the Upstream repo into BitBucket. We use a Fork and Pull model, so I had a personal fork of that Repo in GHE. Now when we moved to BitBucket, I imported my personal fork from GHE into BitBucket.

So, this is where we stand now,
- Upstream Repo imported into BitBucket
- My personal fork imported into BitBucket

Now, when I create a pull request from a branch in my personal repo, I am unable to specify the Upstream repo on the Create Pull Request screen. I know one solution is to not import my personal repo but fork from the imported Upstream repo; but I am also curious to find out whether we can create this workflow connection/mapping, where two imported repos can be connected in such a way that one is recognized as a fork of the other.

Also, I have a bunch of unmerged WIP branches on my old personal fork.

Thanks, and looking forward to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forking is not a native part of Git; it's something implemented as an extra on hosting providers and in their on-premise versions, and the special relationship between the upstream repo and its fork(s) is only defined in the provider's database.

If you've moved to Bitbucket Server (the self-hosted version), then you may be able to edit the database to set up the fork-upstream relationship. That's kind of risky, though, and it isn't an option at all if you've moved to Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org).

You should be able to re-create the link between upstream and your personal fork, though:

1. On Bitbucket, fork the upstream repo. Note the new fork's URL.
2. Update the remote on your local repo to point to the new fork instead of your imported one: `git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:owner/new-fork.git`
3. Push all branches to the new fork: `git push --all`

You can keep your previous import on Bitbucket, or you can remove it if you prefer - but the new fork will be the new place you put your stuff.

Comment: That's true, but Bitbucket (et al.) have functionality to make it easier to synchronize forks with their upstream repos (and vice versa).